# R Studio - Knitr to interactive HTML - Error, execution halted

Tags: r

R Version: 3.2.1; 
RStudio Version: 0.98.1103

I am trying to Knit a R Markdown file.  But am getting the following warnings and error.

```
Warning messages:
1: In FUN(X[[i]], ...) :
  Package 'plyr' not available in repository or locally
2: In FUN(X[[i]], ...) :
  Package 'ggplot2' not available in repository or locally
3: In symlinkExternalPackages(project = project) :
  The following external packages could not be located:
- "plyr", "ggplot2"
Loading required package: reshape2
Warning message:
In library(package, lib.loc = lib.loc, character.only = TRUE, logical.return = TRUE,  :
  there is no package called 'reshape2'
Error in loadNamespace(name) : there is no package called 'rmarkdown'
Calls: :: ... tryCatch -> tryCatchList -> tryCatchOne -> <Anonymous>
Execution halted
```

I've made sure that all of the packages listed are installed, and I've added library(package) for each package listed (ggplot2, reshape2, rmarkdown).  I assume I'm missing something simple.

I also tried moving all my packages back to the default directory: [as suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20569277/error-in-loadnamespacename-there-is-no-package-called-rinside), and checked my .libPaths() to be sure my library directory was there, which it is.

Below is a simplified version of my R markdown file:

````
 ---
    title: "Gain Loss Plot - All Samples"
    author: "Gaius"
    date: "Thursday, September 24, 2015"
    output:
      html_document:
        toc: yes
    runtime: shiny
    ---

    In order to more completely visualize how samples might be related, we are going to create a few interactive plots.

    # Samples by Arm

    ```{r loadlibraries, echo=FALSE}
    library(rmarkdown)
    library(graphics)
    library(ggvis)
    library(ggplot2)
    library(plyr)
    library(reshape2)
    library(data.table)
    library(grDevices)
    ```

    ```{r prepdata, echo=FALSE}

    C01p <- data.table(read.delim("~/_2015_CNV/2015-09-23_CCCC_GLredo_rmvdup-missedlowpurity/chr/01p.txt"))
  #LOAD a bunch of other files just like the one above

    C01p[,Chr.Arm := "01p"]
    #Subset all files as shown in the line above

    #bind all files together
    All.Chrom.Stats  <- rbind(C01p,C01q,C02p,C02q,C03p,C03q,C04p,C04q,C05p,C05q,C06p,C06q,C07p,C07q,C08p,C08q,C09p,C09q,C10p,C10q,C11p,C11q,C12p,C12q,C13q,C14q,C15q,C16p,C16q,C17p,C17q,C18p,C18q,C19p,C19q,C20p,C20q,C21q,C22q)

    #Get just data necessary for creating plots
    Prop.Gain.thresh <- All.Chrom.Stats[Prop.Gain > 0.50]
    Prop.Loss.thresh <- All.Chrom.Stats[Prop.Loss > 0.50]
    ```


    ## Proportion Gained, Threshold > 0.5


    ```{r prop.gain, echo=FALSE}
    all_values <- function(x) {
      if(is.null(x)) return(NULL)
      paste0(names(x), ": ", format(x), collapse = "<br />")
    }

    Prop.Gain.thresh %>% 
      ggvis(~Chr.Arm, ~Prop.Gain) %>% 
      layer_points( fill = ~Sample ) %>% 
      add_tooltip(all_values, "hover")
    ```


    ## Proportion Lost, Threshold > 0.5

    ```{r prop.gain, echo=FALSE}
    all_values <- function(x) {
      if(is.null(x)) return(NULL)
      paste0(rev(names(x)), ": ", rev(format(x)), collapse = "<br />")
    }

    Prop.Loss.thresh %>% 
      ggvis(~Chr.Arm, ~Prop.Loss) %>% 
      layer_points( fill = ~Sample, shape = ~Sample ) %>% 
      add_tooltip(all_values, "hover")
    ```
````

**UPDATE:**  I tried creating a new R markdown file and used the basic template given by RStudio to try to knit. It worked and output the file correctly.

Then I added runtime:shiny to the YAML header. It stopped working (giving same error as above).

I then removed runtime:shiny from the header via UNDO, and it still won't work. Error is the same as in my original question.

Comment: Packages load in interactive session and come up in `sessionInfo()`?

Comment: Yes, everything works perfectly in the R session (loading data, subsetting data, and interactive ggvis plots).

Comment: I tried creating a new R markdown file and used the basic template given by RStudio to try to knit.  It worked.  Then I added runtime:shiny to the YAML header.  It stopped working.  I removed runtime:shiny from the header via UNDO, and it still won't work.

Error is the same as in my original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `runtime: shiny` but you have no shiny elements. In other words you have no `ui` input functions or `server` render (`renderPlot()`, `renderTable()`, etc) functions.   See here for what would be in a shiny presentation: http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/interactive-docs.html

The specific error is likely due to objects not being available across all shiny widgets in a document. You would have to load the package in each widget, or use something like a global.R file.  See the link below:

https://rstudio.github.io/shiny/tutorial/#scoping

Comment: Thank you.  I'll be looking more into Shiny and how to really implement it.  FOLLOWUP QUESTION: Do I need to run with Shiny to use the add_tooltip() function?  If not...I've taken out runtime: shiny, and am still having the same error.

Comment: No, `add_tooltip` doesn't need to be run within Shiny.  If you take out `runtime: shiny` you need to resave the file and be sure the new output format is recognized.  In other words, if you are suing RStudio, be sure it says "Knit HTML" in the toolbar, and *not* "Run Document".  Sometimes changes in the YAML header aren't immediately recognized.

Comment: You can also run it from the command line to be sure.  You want `knitr::knit2html('~/path/to/file')` and not `shiny::runApp()`